# 18.04 Ubuntu with Wayland, screen will not display in portrait

Tags: nvidia, 18.04, multiple-monitors, wayland, display-rotation

I've just updated to 18.04 from 16.10. When using Ubuntu with Wayland, if I rotate the view of either of my two monitors in the display settings, the rotated monitor will not receive a signal.

When running just Ubuntu, I can rotate my monitors just fine.  However, if I have a monitor set as rotated and try to log out then back in on Ubuntu with Wayland, my machine freezes.

The end goal is to have per-monitor fractal scaling, ideally through Wayland but I am willing to try anything else.  I'm going to do a clean install tonight if all else fails but was hoping one of you could offer me some solutions.

Possible relevant specs:

CPU: 8700k

GPU: 1080ti with 390.77 driver

Display 1: 1920x1080 60hz

Display 2: 4k 60hz

Answer (score 0):

I just reported this issue.  https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/issues/304

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/issues/216 seems to be the fix.
Perhaps Ubuntu 18.04 doesn't have this version yet.