# Ubuntu 18.04 - Screen goes black when rotated to portrait mode

Tags: 18.04, touchscreen, display-rotation

I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 on a Lenovo X1 Yoga with touchscreen capabilities.  When I rotate the laptop to portrait mode, the screen just goes black.  When I rotate back to landscape, the screen returns.

EDIT: Just found out this only happens in Wayland, X seems to work fine.
The issue in this post seems to be the same as my issue: [18.04 Ubuntu with Wayland, screen will not display in portrait](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1057893/18-04-ubuntu-with-wayland-screen-will-not-display-in-portrait)

Comment: I'm back to version 18.04 and the problem returned, does anyone know how to fix for this version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved updating to Ubuntu 18.10.

I can now pick-up the laptop, rotate it to portrait mode and the screen follows.